# Validate redirection implimentation

Tags: c#, xml

Let's assume i have 20 url's in list, can anyone help me getting response of all these 20 url's in minimal time[like redirection implimentation verifier].

```
    XmlNodeList lst = doc.SelectNodes("//match");
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
    {
              XmlNode node = lst[i];
              string URL = lst[i].InnerText;

              var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
              HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
              string responseURI = response.ResponseUri.ToString();

               //XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
               //DataTable table = GetYourTable();
               //workbook.Worksheets.Add(table);
    }
```

The above method is taking too much time, I am not good in "thread" concept, so please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Parallel.ForEach/For.

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Parallel.For(0, lst.Count, index =>
{
          string URL = lst[index].InnerText;

          var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
          HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
          string responseURI = response.ResponseUri.ToString();

});
```

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

> A ForEach loop works like a For loop. The source collection is
>   partitioned and the work is scheduled on multiple threads based on the
>   system environment. The more processors on the system, the faster the
>   parallel method runs.

You can use this to either fill a list with you responses and proccess it further or if you want to put in on the GUI, call invoke() to a UI control to schedule it in their respective message loop.

Side note: XmlNodeList exposes an enumerator, so there is no need to access it by the [] operator; foreach will provide you with all the child elements.

**EDIT:** It seems like C# cannot resolve the XmlNodeList enumerator to XmlNode. I have no idea why to be honest - but you can use Parallel.For instead

Comment: Hi Owlsolo, thank your resonse. but i am getting below error. please guide me further.                                                                                                       http://i.stack.imgur.com/uia6Z.png

Comment: For some reason Foreach seems to not work on XmlNodeList. See my edit.